# i m trying to use LiteDb, how can i save hebrew or other languges that are not english in the database

Tags: utf-8, litedb

i m trying to insert to a collection data with hebrew characters
is it possible to work with LiteDb in hebrew? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

All strings in LiteDB are stored in UTF8. You shouldn't have any problem to store in any language.

In v5 you database are created using current culture info and you can change it by `Rebuild` your database